# Ruby 1.9.2 not installing on OSX?

Tags: ruby, rvm

1. I've got Xcode 3.2.1
2. I've installed Git and RVM
3. I've installed Ruby 1.9.2, it's installed 100%
4. I run `ruby -v` but  instead of seeing

   ```
   ruby 1.9.2p0 (2010-08-18 revision 29036) [x86_64-darwin10.4.0]
   ```

   I see

   ```
   ruby 1.8.7 (2009-06-12 patchlevel 174) [universal-darwin10.0]
   ```

I don't see what I could be going wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
rvm 1.9.2
```

Or

```
rvm --default 1.9.2
```

It is possible to use a .rvmrc to do that for the directory you cd into as well.

Answer (score 1):

Have you selected the version of ruby you want to use with rvm?  As in [this](http://amerine.net/2010/02/24/rvm-rails3-ruby-1-9-2-setup.html)? Note the "rvm 1.9.2" line hidden away after the rvm and ruby installs.

Answer (score 1):

Type in 'rvm 1.9.2' and then type 'ruby -v'... did you do that? It looks like the Ruby 1.8.7 on your machine is the one included with OS X.